# Countif linked to all sheets in the workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, formulas

Hello I am trying to use countif to add up how many cells have January in. For example I have 40 worksheets and I need to find out how many of them contain january in the date in cell C3 on all of the sheets. and put the answer in another sheet.

Comment: Questions 1) Are your 40 sheet names all in the format "Sheet1" all the way to "Sheet40"?  2) Are the dates in cell C3 text or an Excel date stored as a number and displayed as text.  you can test it with `=ISTEXT(C3)` or `=ISNUMBER(C3)`

Comment: no they are peoples names, and the date is written in the format eg: 23 january 2016 =ISTEXT(C3) is saying false, sorry not to good with spread sheets, I am learning as I go. :)

Comment: I did a little googling and I found an answer for you but the approach I count will require you to index your sheet names in a column somewhere.  The better question is are you allowed to use VBA and run some code to get an answer or strictly speaking does it have to be a formula?

Comment: it has to be a formula

Comment: ARG I have it working for text, I cant get it working for month.

Comment: What you are looking for is a 3D COUNTIF formula.  Its Called 3D because 2D is is rows and columns for dimensions, in this case the third dimension is worksheets.  That might give you something to google.

Comment: whats the text formula because i need that as well, i need to find out how many cells C11 in all the sheets contain the word Completed

Comment: thank you i will google that. :)

Answer (score 1):

OPTION 1)  Formula Method

1) Write out a list of all the names of your sheets in a column.
2) On the "Formulas" ribbon, select Define Name.
3) Give it a name in the top box, ie. SHEETNAMES

Then use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF((INDIRECT("'"&SHEETNAMES&"'!C11")),"Completed"))
```

I would have thought the formula for your original question would have been very similar but it keeps showing up as an error.  I have been using the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(INDIRECT("'"&SHEETNAMES&"'!C3"))=1))
```

Comment: THANK YOU, BUT WHERE DO I PUT THE FORMULA

Comment: in whatever cell you want to see the count of C11 being equal to "Complete"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [3-D formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-3-D-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-40ca91ff-9dcb-4ad1-99d2-787d0bc888b6), but unfortunately, the only formulas that allow 3-D references are mathematical functions that don't have much in the way of logic (no `IF`s, `AND`s, etc.). If you restructure your workbook a little bit to, say, add `IF(C3="January",1,0)` in `Z3` on each sheet, then you can do `SUM(Sheet2:Sheet40!Z3)` on your summary sheet.